# SBT 0.12.1 downloads wrong SNAPSHOT

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, ivy

I deploy some SNAPSHOT dependencies to Sonatype OSS using `mvn`.  Sonatype stores a number of old snapshots for each coordinate.  A directory listing of my deployed SNAPSHOTs is at the bottom of this question.

In my `sbt` Play! project, I added the Sonatype SNAPSHOT repository as a resolver.

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  // Add your own project settings here
  resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
)
```

However, the wrong SNAPSHOT is downloaded each time.  While `sbt` should download the last deployed SNAPSHOT (20130109.225335-6) but it downloads the first deployed SNAPSHOT (20130109.210948-1).

```
$ rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache/edu.washington.cs.knowitall.chunkedextractor/
$ sbt clean compile
[info] Loading project definition from /scratch/github/knowitall/documentextractor/project
[info] Set current project to documentextractor (in build file:/scratch/github/knowitall/documentextractor/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 9, 2013 3:06:41 PM
[info] Updating {file:/scratch/github/knowitall/documentextractor/}documentextractor...
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/edu/washington/cs/knowitall/chunkedextractor/chunkedextractor_2.9.2/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] edu.washington.cs.knowitall.chunkedextractor#chunkedextractor_2.9.2;1.0.1-SNAPSHOT!chunkedextractor_2.9.2.jar (1079ms)
[info] Done updating.
```

Any idea how I can fix this and make `sbt` download the most recent SNAPSHOT?  Is this an `sbt`-specific problem or does it have to do with `Play!`?

Here is the directory listing of my artifact's snapshots on Sonatype.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/edu/washington/cs/knowitall/chunkedextractor/chunkedextractor_2.9.2/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

```
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1-javadoc.jar   Wed Jan 09 15:09:55 CST 2013    361379   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1-javadoc.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 15:09:56 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1-javadoc.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 15:09:56 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1-sources.jar   Wed Jan 09 15:09:53 CST 2013    17175    
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1-sources.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 15:09:54 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1-sources.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 15:09:53 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1.jar   Wed Jan 09 15:09:48 CST 2013    178994   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 15:09:49 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 15:09:49 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1.pom   Wed Jan 09 15:09:49 CST 2013    3725     
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1.pom.md5   Wed Jan 09 15:09:50 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.210948-1.pom.sha1  Wed Jan 09 15:09:50 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2-javadoc.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:21:29 CST 2013    363291   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2-javadoc.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:21:30 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2-javadoc.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:21:30 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2-sources.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:21:27 CST 2013    17195    
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2-sources.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:21:27 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2-sources.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:21:27 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:21:21 CST 2013    177267   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:21:22 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:21:22 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2.pom   Wed Jan 09 16:21:23 CST 2013    3725     
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2.pom.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:21:23 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.222121-2.pom.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:21:23 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3-javadoc.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:30:25 CST 2013    363291   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3-javadoc.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:30:26 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3-javadoc.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:30:25 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3-sources.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:30:22 CST 2013    17195    
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3-sources.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:30:23 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3-sources.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:30:23 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:30:18 CST 2013    177267   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:30:18 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:30:18 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3.pom   Wed Jan 09 16:30:19 CST 2013    3725     
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3.pom.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:30:19 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.223017-3.pom.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:30:19 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4-javadoc.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:47:24 CST 2013    363343   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4-javadoc.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:47:24 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4-javadoc.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:47:24 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4-sources.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:47:21 CST 2013    17198    
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4-sources.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:47:22 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4-sources.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:47:22 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:47:17 CST 2013    177369   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:47:18 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:47:17 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4.pom   Wed Jan 09 16:47:18 CST 2013    3725     
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4.pom.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:47:19 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.224717-4.pom.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:47:18 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5-javadoc.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:52:52 CST 2013    363343   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5-javadoc.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:52:52 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5-javadoc.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:52:52 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5-sources.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:52:49 CST 2013    17198    
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5-sources.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:52:50 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5-sources.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:52:50 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:52:45 CST 2013    177369   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:52:46 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:52:45 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5.pom   Wed Jan 09 16:52:46 CST 2013    3725     
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5.pom.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:52:47 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225244-5.pom.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:52:46 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6-javadoc.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:53:42 CST 2013    363343   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6-javadoc.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:53:43 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6-javadoc.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:53:42 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6-sources.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:53:40 CST 2013    17198    
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6-sources.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:53:40 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6-sources.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:53:40 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6.jar   Wed Jan 09 16:53:35 CST 2013    177369   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6.jar.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:53:36 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6.jar.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:53:36 CST 2013    40   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6.pom   Wed Jan 09 16:53:36 CST 2013    3725     
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6.pom.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:53:37 CST 2013    32   
chunkedextractor_2.9.2-1.0.1-20130109.225335-6.pom.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:53:37 CST 2013    40   
maven-metadata.xml   Wed Jan 09 16:53:43 CST 2013    1244     
maven-metadata.xml.md5   Wed Jan 09 16:53:44 CST 2013    32   
maven-metadata.xml.sha1  Wed Jan 09 16:53:43 CST 2013    40
```

UPDATE: `build.properties` specifies `sbt.version=0.11.3`.  Maybe Play is forcing this older version of `sbt`.

Comment: Does this still happen with sbt 0.13.13?

Answer (score 0):

Try if one of these might help you:

1) run 'update'

2) modify dependency to "groupId" %% "artifactId" % "version" changing() and run 'update'

Comment: I've ran `update` to no effect.  I also delete the dependency manually from my ivy2 cache and it keeps downloading the wrong snapshot.

Comment: I thought `changing()` was working because it jumped up to the latest SNAPSHOT, but when I deployed a new snapshot, I couldn't get `sbt` to use the latest.  I think the problem has to do with `sbt` choosing the first SNAPSHOT of the most recent day.

Comment: SBT should work fine with SNAPSHOTs. You can change your sbt version in build.properties to 0.12.2-RC2 and see if that has any effect. changing() basically tells sbt to get snapshot again each time you call 'update'.

Comment: I can't use sbt 0.12.2-RC2 because I'm using play.  I'll start getting the error `unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.0.4: not found`.

Comment: Could you create a fresh application with Play 2.1-RC2 and see if that finds the latest snapshot?